# How to select some value and column name which content a specific value in mysql table

Tags: sql, select, field

I have a product table like

```
order_id | pr1 | pr2 | pro3 | pro4 | price

AB5487   | on  | on  |      | on   | 120

AB5587   | on  | on  |  on  |      | 120
```

I want to get price and fields name which content 'on' where order_id is 'AB5487'

Comment: Please add the information which Database Management System do you use.

Comment: Fix your table structure. You need to unpivot the data to do this.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply but i can't understand what do you mean by Database Management System, i am using mysql Database.